# count occurencies of a word

Tags: python, python-2.7, count

I checked similar topics, but the results are poor.

I have a file like this:

```
S1_22   45317082    31  0   9   22  1543
S1_23   3859606 40  3   3   34  2111
S1_24   48088383    49  6   1   42  2400
S1_25   43387855    39  1   7   31  2425
S1_26   39016907    39  2   7   30  1977
S1_27   57612149    23  0   0   23  1843
S1_28   42505824    23  1   1   21  1092
S1_29   54856684    18  0   2   16  1018
S1_29   54856684    18  0   2   16  1018
S1_29   54856684    18  0   2   16  1018
S1_29   54856684    18  0   2   16  1018
```

I wanted to count occurencies of words in first column, and based on that write the output file with additional field stating uniq if count == 1 and multi if count > 0

I produced the code:

```
import csv
import collections

infile = 'Results'

names = collections.Counter()

with open(infile) as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t'):
        names[row[0]] += 1
    print names[row[0]],row[0]
```

but it doesn't work properly

I can't put everything into list, since the file is too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this code to work you should indent your `print` statement:

```
    names[row[0]] += 1
    print names[row[0]],row[0]
```

But what you actually want is:

```
import csv
import collections

infile = 'Result'

names = collections.Counter()

with open(infile) as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t'):
        names[row[0]] += 1

for name, count in names.iteritems():
    print name, count
```

**Edit: To show the rest of the row, you can use a second dict, as in:**

```
names = collections.Counter()
rows = {}

with open(infile) as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t'):
        rows[row[0]] = row
        names[row[0]] += 1

for name, count in names.iteritems():
    print rows[name], count
```

Answer (score 1):

The print statement at the end does not look like what you want. Because of its indentation it is only executed once. It will print S1_29, since that is the value of `row[0]` in the last iteration of the loop.

You're on the right track. Instead of that print statement, just iterate through the keys & values of the counter and check if each value is greater than or equal to 1.